# Problem with ibid with \footcite and \cite in Biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

I am having some problem with the `\footcite` and `\cite` commands in how they behave when it comes to printing the word "ibid" with subsequent references to the same work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate,sorting=nyt,cmsdate=both,maxcitenames=2]{biblatex-chicago} 

\renewbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{\printtext[bibhyperref]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}} 

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

A footnote with the footcite command;\footcite[See][]{danielson1979} a second footnote using the footcite command;\footcite[][]{danielson1979} and then a footnote using cite inside the footnote command.\footnote{\cite{danielson1979}}

\end{document}
```

For this example I have used this bib-file:

```
@article{danielson1979,
    title = {Toward the Analysis of Vernacular Texts: The Supernatural Narrative in Oral and Popular Print Sources},
    volume = {16},
    number = {3},
    journal = {Journal of the Folklore Institute},
    author = {Larry Danielson}, 
    year = {1979},
    pages = {130–-154}
}
```

The result I get is this:

[image]
[image]

For some reason the "ibid" is formatted differently if I use a direct `\footcite` or if I put a `\cite` command inside a `\footnote` command.

After doing some reading here I found that putting `\cite` commands incite `\footnote` is not considered the proper way to use these commands. I do however on occasion need to make footnotes with several references and somewhat longer explaining texts, and I can't see how it would work to put all that in the second `[...]` in the `\footcite` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\Cite` with a  capital "C" if you start a `\footnote` with a citation.

`biblatex` makes sure that the content of `\footcite`s is capitalised correctly as if the footnote forms a complete sentence (it starts with a capital letter and ends with a period). If you manually put a citation into a `\footnote` you need to *manually* make sure that `biblatex` uses the correct capitalisation by choosing `\Cite` – the `\cite` variation for the beginning of sentences – if the footnote starts with the citation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate]{biblatex-chicago} 

\renewbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{\printtext[bibhyperref]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}} 

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
A footnote with the footcite command;\footcite[See][]{sigfridsson}
a second footnote using the footcite command;\footcite[][]{sigfridsson}
and then a footnote using cite inside the footnote command.\footnote{\Cite{sigfridsson}}
\end{document}
```

[image: 1. See Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998.//2. Ibid.//3. Ibid.]

---

I think it is perfectly fine to have a `\Cite` or `\cite` in a `\footnote` as long as the footnote contains (considerably) more than just that citation.

There is no good reason to write

```
\footnote{\Cite[See][380-382]{sigfridsson}}
```

where

```
\footcite[See][380-382]{sigfridsson}
```

would do the same. But there absolutely is an argument to be made that

```
\footnote{\Cite{sigfridsson}. There is considerable disagreement about this in the literature. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}
```

is easier on the eye and maybe even more logical than

```
\footcite[There is considerable disagreement about this in the literature. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.]{sigfridsson}
```